# Recommended method for filling missing values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

using pandas, I want to fill the missing values of column `b` from the following DataFrame `df1` with the values from the column `a`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=[1, 2, 3], b=[1, np.nan, 3]))
mask = pd.isnull(df1.b)
```

it seems that I can use three different ways:

```
# first
df1.loc[mask, 'b'] = df1.loc[mask, 'a']
#second
df1.loc[mask, 'b'] = df1.a
# third
df1.fillna(value=dict(b=df1.a), inplace=True)
```

All of them lead to the same result. Is there a recommended method?

Thanks.

Comment: They all have advantages and disadvantages. What's most useful to you?

Comment: I think it is not a question of being useful. I am a bit puzzled by the second (and also a bit by the third) as it gets the proper indexes on the right DataFrame while it is explicit in the first case.

Comment: The third should be self explanatory. You're using API designed to solve this problem. One, pandas aligns the indices automatically, that's one reason why pandas is awesome. Two, you're doing the work for pandas by eliminating the indices it was going to take care of anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand that, for the third solution, it is dealt with under the hood. As for the first one, I, indeed, do the job as I both select the relevant rows in `b` and `a`. The less "straightforward" for me is in fact the second. As one can replace `df1.a` by another series (independent of df1), I find a bit fascinating that pandas "propagates" the right row indexes from the left of the equation to the right one.

Comment: For the second one, if you pass a list or array, it must be the same size. And if you do, it aligns based on order. If you use a series, it has an index to look up values with. If an index is missing, you get nan

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Then we do timing :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=[1, 2, 3], b=[1, np.nan, 3]))
mask = pd.isnull(df1.b)
%timeit df1.loc[mask, 'b'] = df1.loc[mask, 'a']
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 ms per loop
%timeit df1.loc[mask, 'b'] = df1.a
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 ms per loop
%timeit df1.fillna(value=dict(b=df1.a), inplace=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 215 µs per loop

#3rd one is the fastest among three.
```

EDIT method from @Zero

```
%timeit df1.b = df1.b.fillna(df1.a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 371 µs per loop
%timeit df1.b.fillna(df1.a, inplace=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 210 µs per loop
```

Comment: Another, `df1.b = df1.b.fillna(df1.a)` or `df1.b.fillna(df1.a, inplace=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use pandas [where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with:

```
df1["b"].where(df1["b"]==np.nan, other=df1["a"],inplace=True)

print(df1)

   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  3.0
```